# React-Native when compilating typescript with metro bundlere there is error

Tags: typescript, react-native, macos, metro-bundler

with my new colleague we try to run our application on his MacBook (Ventura OS), but we wera able only to run it on Android Simulator. On IOS there is this error which we are unable to debug. We really tried to debug and think of every possibility during last 3 days so. We don know how to solve it.

Does any one has the same issue.

Code that breaks look like this

```
export const useTranslation = (): TranslationFunction => {
  const translations: TranslationPair[] = useAppSelector(
    state => state.language.translations,
  );

  const translationsMap = useMemo(() => {
    const map = new Map<string, string>();
    for (const pair of translations) {
      map.set(pair.key, pair.value);
    }
    return map;
  }, [translations]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some ES5+ like Map, Set,... are not natively fully supported by React Native Run-times, especially Hermes Engine.

Replace Map with standard  Object `{}` or try to use JavaScriptCore Engine

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion unfortunately this is not possible we would have to rewrite every case in the app. This is not the solution why Android works and IOS dont in this case?

Comment: What current Engine your are using on iOS ? JavaScriptCore or Hermes?

Comment: Try to switch between those engines - https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes#ios